# N dimensional arrays - Python/Numpy

Tags: python, math, numpy, scipy

just wondering if there is any clever way to do the following.

**I have an N dimensional array representing a 3x3 grid**

```
grid = [[1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9]]
```

In order to get the **first row** I do the following:

```
grid[0][0:3]
>> [1,2,3]
```

In order to get the **first column** I would like to do something like this (even though it is not possible):

```
grid[0:3][0]
>> [1,4,7]
```

**Does NumPy support anything similar to this by chance?**

---

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is something like that in Numpy:

```
import numpy as np

grid = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                 [4, 5, 6],
                 [7, 8, 9]])

grid[0,:]
# array([1, 2, 3])

grid[:,0]
# array([1, 4, 7])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` to transpose a matrix represented as a list of lists:

```
>>> zip(*grid)[0]
(1, 4, 7)
```

Anything more than just that, and I'd use Numpy.

Answer (score 1):

To get the columns in Python you could use:

```
[row[0] for row in grid]
>>> [1,4,7]
```

You could rewrite your code for getting the row as

```
grid[0][:]
```

because `[:]` just copies the whole array, no need to add the indices.

However, depending on what you want to achieve, I'd say it's better to just write a small matrix class to hide this implementation stuff.

Comment: Don't write your own matrix classes. Use good matrix classes already provided.

Comment: @eumiro: You're absolutely right. Do you have a specific class in mind?

Comment: @eumiro: Numpy seems to be a little overkill in many cases to me. As far as I can see one even has to install a binary.

Comment: there is a debian/ubuntu/(other) package for numpy. Once installed, serves always.